# Remove product-category slug from Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

I'm having problems with my pagination. The root of the problem is that the product categories goes down 3 levels.

I used the script from the timersys gist: https://gist.github.com/timersys/78a2305d810c27efcb10ce62712d1d95

Then to accommodate the 3rd level of the categories I added the following:

```
add_filter('request', function( $vars ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(isset($vars['error'])){
        $lastVar = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $vars['attachment'] = $lastVar;
    }
    //rest of the code
}
```

from here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258053/remove-product-category-slug-plugin-works-with-1-subcategroy-not-with-2/258085#258085

So everything is working and filtering correctly now except when I change pages on the pagination, it takes me to a single product instead of the next page.